React Native Navigation: Conditional rendering and screen transitions in nested navigators
I'm experiencing layout jumps and abrupt transitions when conditionally rendering headers and tab bars in a deeply nested React Navigation structure. The issue occurs when navigating between screens that show/hide navigation headers/tabs conditionally.
Navigation Structure
DrawerNavigator (Drawer)
└── TopLevelNavigator (Stack) - Renders Main header with the logo
    └── MainBottomTabNavigator (Bottom Tabs) - Renders bottom tabs
        ├── BookOrDineTabNavigator (Material Top Tabs) - Renders top tabs
        │   ├── BookingNavigator (Stack) - Hides Main header and top tabs when navigating inside
        │   └── DineNavigator (Stack) - Hides Main header and top tabs when navigating inside
        ├── OwnNavigator (Stack) - Hides Main header when navigating inside
        ├── ShopNavigator (Stack) - Hides Main header when navigating inside
        ├── Single screen 1
        └── Single screen 2

When navigating to screens that don't show the header/tabs:

Components disappear abruptly before transitioning (I understand this is because the element that disappears is not part of the current navigation, that's why it doesn't animate smoothly with the transition).
Layout doesn't adjust smoothly to height changes.
Footer components float over empty spaces that maintain the previous header/tab heights (I believe its cause comes from the previous mentioned problem).

Example:

BookOrDineNavigator Dine page
Before navigation occurs
During transition
After navigating

Code Implementation
    // TopLevelNavigator.jsx
    export function TopLevelNavigator() {
      const {showMainHeader} = useAppNavigation();
      
      return (
        <Stack.Navigator
          screenOptions={() => ({
            header: () => <MainHeader />,
            headerShown: showMainHeader,
            // ...
          })}
        >
          {/* ... */}
        </Stack.Navigator>
      );
    }

    // MainBottomTabNavigator.jsx
    export function MainBottomTabNavigator() {
      const {setShowMainHeader} = useAppNavigation();
      const bottomTabNavigatorValue = useBottomTabNavigatorContextProviderValue();
      
      return (
        <BottomTabNavigatorContext.Provider value={bottomTabNavigatorValue}>
          <Tab.Navigator
            tabBar={(props) =>
              bottomTabNavigatorValue.showBottomTabs && (
                <CustomBottomTabBar {...props} />
              )
            }
            screenListeners={({route}) => ({
              focus: () => {
                setShowMainHeader(tabRoutesWithoutInnerNavigators.includes(route.name));
              },
            })}
          >
            {/* ... */}
          </Tab.Navigator>
        </BottomTabNavigatorContext.Provider>
      );
    }

    // BookingNavigator.jsx
    export function BookingNavigator() {
      const {setShowMainHeader} = useAppNavigation();
      const {setShowBottomTabs} = useBottomTabNavigator();
      
      return (
        <Stack.Navigator
          screenListeners={({route}) => ({
            focus: () => {
              setShowMainHeader(route.name === INITIAL_ROUTE);
              setShowBottomTabs(bookingRoutesWithBottomTabs.includes(route.name));
            },
          })}
        >
          {/* ... */}
        </Stack.Navigator>
      );
    }

